# Multi-column Index on a filter & sort by query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am executing an query of type:

**Query:**

```
select * 
from entity 
where last_updation_date between <START-VALUE-1> and <END-VALUE>  
order by entity_id limit <XYZ> offset <ABC>;
```

Table: entity also has an index (Btree) on it as such -

**Index:**

```
create index i_last_updation_date_idx 
   on entity using btree  (last_updation_date, entity_id)
```

But it seems that this type of index is of no use on the above query. Can anyone suggest what kind of index would better serve this type of use-case?

**Some Additional Information -**

The Table is quite huge, contains around 1 TB data. The data type of last_updation_date is timestamp with precision set to 29 & scale set to 6.

The table has around 1,81,79,77,192 rows. Regarding entity_id - it the primary key generated by a sequence generator. last_updation_date is pretty random (gets updated whenever a client updates the entity). The value of last_updation_date ranges from timestamp 16,01,51,39,96,400 ms (i.e. 1st Oct 2020) to 16,04,97,00,00,000 ms (i.e. 1st Nov 2021)

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why this correct looking index might not be getting used.  The statistics of your table might be such that it is faster to do a table scan.  Another possibility is that your table is very small, also limiting the use of any index.  You should check for both of these.

Comment: What are the data types? In particular, is last_updation_date a timestamp, or actually a date?

Comment: The Table is quite huge, contains around 1TB data. The data type of last_updation_date is  timestamp with precision = 29 & scale set to 6.

Comment: What are the statistics of your table and index column? did you need to `select *` for your case?

Comment: As for the table there are 1,81,79,77,192 rows. Regarding entity_id - it the primary key generated by a sequence generator. last_updation_date is pretty random (gets updated whenever a client updates the entity). The value of last_updation_date ranges from timestamp 16,01,51,39,96,400 ms (i.e. 1st Oct 2020) to 16,04,97,00,00,000 ms (i.e. 1st Nov 2021).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able solve this problem by modifying my query (**order by clause**) as such -

```
select * 
from entity 
where last_updation_date between <START-VALUE-1> and <END-VALUE>  
order by last_updation_date, entity_id limit <XYZ> offset <ABC>;
```

This query was making use of the index i mentioned.

It was not a strict requirement for me to order the results specifically by entity_id. All i needed was an approach to fetch results in a paginated manner using LIMIT & OFFSET. And simply using last_updation_date for pagination would not work because they are not guaranteed to be unique always (there can be duplicates). Hence, i used both last_updation_date & entity_id.